# iOS Files.app doesn't connect to SMB share "connection to the server has failed"

Tags: ios, network, smb, files.app

I can't connect to an SMB share using my iPhone (iOS 15.3.1); when I try to connect to the same hostname, same port, same credentials on my Mac it works fine (I copy-pasted so there's no possibility for typos). What's wrong?

The server I have is a TrueNAS server (TrueNAS CORE 12.0-U8) using No-IP dynamic IP service, I tried using a different port, it didn't help. Also, the web interface of the server opens up fine, which proves

1. the dynamic IP is indeed working
2. the port 50080 is open.

I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Which version of iOS do you have? What is the version of your TrueNAS server? Could you increase the verbosity of the SMB server and check if you can find any hints in the logs?

Comment: @jaume iOS 15.3.1, TrueNAS-12.0-U8.
I just checked the logs in `/var/log/samba4`. I looked carefully at the file `auth_audit.log` as it seems to be the log file for all the incoming samba authentications. I attempted to connect with my iPhone and didn't see a such connection being recorded in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It seems from iOS, 445 (samba defautl) is the only port which is supported.

I tested it with Termius app using different ports, eg:
`ssh -L 9999:localhost:445 SSH_SERVER_WITH_SAMBA` --> it's not working

But if I use the default port number:
`ssh -L 445:localhost:445 SSH_SERVER_WITH_SAMBA` --> then it's working fine

note: For Termius you have to enable the location service on iOS devices. https://support.termius.com/hc/en-us/articles/4402044543897#location